# Multiple Dataset AmstockChart with multiple Axis

Tags: amcharts

I want to implement [multiple value axis](http://www.amcharts.com/tips/multiple-value-axes-stock-chart/) in following amchart sample:
https://www.amcharts.com/demos/multiple-data-sets/

Multiple axis example: http://www.amcharts.com/tips/multiple-value-axes-stock-chart/

I tried a lot but I think I miss some minor thing. 
**Is there any way to combine above charts (multi value and multi data Set) and create a multiple value axis multiple data sets Chart?**

Examples with jsfiddle will work best for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this myself. Hope this becomes helpful to someone. Here is the solution:

```js
 AmCharts.ready(function () {
        generateChartData();
        createStockChart();
    });

  var colors = [
        "#FF6600", "#B0DE09", "#FCD202", "#2A0CD0",
        "#CD0D74", "#CC0000", "#00CC00", "#0000CC", "#DDDDDD",
        "#999999", "#333333", "#990000", "#0D8ECF"
    ];
    var chartData1 = [];
    var chartData2 = [];
    var chartData3 = [];
    var chartData4 = [];
    
    function generateChartData() {
        var firstDate = new Date();
        firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate() - 500);
        firstDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        
        for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            var newDate = new Date(firstDate);
            newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate()+i);
            newDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
   
      var value1 = Math.round(Math.random() * (40 + i)) + 100 + i;
            var value2 = Math.round(Math.random() * (100 + i)) + 200 + i;
            var value3 = Math.round(Math.random() * (100 + i)) + 200;
            var value4 = Math.round(Math.random() * (100 + i)) + 200 + i;
   
            chartData1.push({date: newDate,value1: value1});
            chartData2.push({date: newDate,value2: value2});
            chartData3.push({date: newDate,value3: value3});
            chartData4.push({date: newDate,value4: value4});
        }
    }
    
    function createStockChart() {
        var chart = new AmCharts.AmStockChart();
        chart.pathToImages = "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/";
        
  var dataSet1 = new AmCharts.DataSet();
        dataSet1.fieldMappings = [{fromField: "value1", toField: "value1"}];
        dataSet1.dataProvider = chartData1;
        dataSet1.categoryField = "date";
        dataSet1.title = "Value1";
        dataSet1.color = colors[0];
  
    var dataSet2 = new AmCharts.DataSet();
        dataSet2.fieldMappings = [{fromField: "value2", toField: "value2"}];
        dataSet2.dataProvider = chartData2;
        dataSet2.categoryField = "date";
        dataSet2.title = "Value2";
        dataSet2.color = colors[1];
  
    var dataSet3 = new AmCharts.DataSet();
        dataSet3.fieldMappings = [{fromField: "value3", toField: "value3"}];
        dataSet3.dataProvider = chartData3;
        dataSet3.categoryField = "date";
        dataSet3.title = "Value3";
        dataSet3.color = colors[2];
  
    var dataSet4 = new AmCharts.DataSet();
        dataSet4.fieldMappings = [{fromField: "value4", toField: "value4"}];
        dataSet4.dataProvider = chartData4;
        dataSet4.categoryField = "date";
    dataSet4.title = "Value4";
    dataSet4.color = colors[3];
  
        // set data sets to the chart
        chart.dataSets = [dataSet1,dataSet2,dataSet3,dataSet4];

        // PANELS ///////////////////////////////////////////                                                  
        // first stock panel
        var stockPanel = new AmCharts.StockPanel();
        stockPanel.recalculateToPercents = "never";
        stockPanel.title = "Volume";
    
        var categoryAxesSettings = new AmCharts.CategoryAxesSettings();
        categoryAxesSettings.minPeriod = "DD";
        chart.categoryAxesSettings = categoryAxesSettings;

        // apply custom style for value axes
        var valueAxesSettings = new AmCharts.ValueAxesSettings();
        valueAxesSettings.axisAlpha = 1; 
        valueAxesSettings.gridThickness = 0;
        valueAxesSettings.axisThickness = 2; 
        valueAxesSettings.inside = false;
        chart.valueAxesSettings = valueAxesSettings;
    
        // apply custom style for panels settings
        var panelsSettings = new AmCharts.PanelsSettings();
        panelsSettings.marginLeft = 100;
        panelsSettings.marginRight = 100;
    chart.panelsSettings = panelsSettings;
    
        // add first value axes
        var valueAxis1 = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
        valueAxis1.axisColor = colors[0];
        valueAxis1.color = colors[0];
        valueAxis1.offset = 0;
        stockPanel.addValueAxis(valueAxis1);
    
        // add second value axes
        var valueAxis2 = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
        valueAxis2.axisColor = colors[1];
        valueAxis2.color = colors[1];
        valueAxis2.offset = 0;
        valueAxis2.position = "right";
        stockPanel.addValueAxis(valueAxis2);
    
        // add third value axes
        var valueAxis3 = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
        valueAxis3.axisColor = colors[2];
        valueAxis3.color = colors[2];
        valueAxis3.offset = 50;
        stockPanel.addValueAxis(valueAxis3);
    
        // add fourth value axes
        var valueAxis4 = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
        valueAxis4.axisColor = colors[3];
        valueAxis4.color = colors[3];
        valueAxis4.offset = 50;
        valueAxis4.position = "right";
        stockPanel.addValueAxis(valueAxis4);
    
        // graph of first stock panel
    var graph1 = new AmCharts.StockGraph();
        graph1.valueField = "value1";
    graph1.comparable = true;
    graph1.title = "Value1";
        graph1.useDataSetColors = false;
        graph1.lineColor = colors[0];
        graph1.bullet = "round";
        graph1.bulletBorderColor = "#FFFFFF";
        graph1.bulletBorderAlpha = 1;
        graph1.balloonText = "[[title]]:<b>[[value]]</b>";
        graph1.compareGraphBalloonText = "[[title]]:<b>[[value]]</b>";
        graph1.compareGraphBullet = "round";
        graph1.compareGraphBulletBorderColor = "#FFFFFF";
        graph1.compareGraphBulletBorderAlpha = 1;
        graph1.valueAxis = valueAxis1;
    stockPanel.addStockGraph(graph1);
    
        // graph of second stock panel
        var graph2 = new AmCharts.StockGraph();
        graph2.valueField = "value2";
    graph2.comparable = true;
        graph2.title = "Value2";
        graph2.useDataSetColors = false;
        graph2.lineColor = colors[1];
        graph2.bullet = "round";
        graph2.bulletBorderColor = "#FFFFFF";
        graph2.bulletBorderAlpha = 1;
        graph2.balloonText = "[[title]]:<b>[[value]]</b>";
        graph2.compareGraphBalloonText = "[[title]]:<b>[[value]]</b>";
        graph2.compareGraphBullet = "round";
        graph2.compareGraphBulletBorderColor = "#FFFFFF";
        graph2.compareGraphBulletBorderAlpha = 1;
        graph2.valueAxis = valueAxis2;
    stockPanel.addStockGraph(graph2);
    
        // graph of third stock panel
        var graph3 = new AmCharts.StockGraph();
        graph3.valueField = "value3";
    graph3.comparable = true;
        graph3.title = "Value3";
        graph3.useDataSetColors = false;
        graph3.lineColor = colors[2];
        graph3.bullet = "round";
        graph3.bulletBorderColor = "#FFFFFF";
        graph3.bulletBorderAlpha = 1;
        graph3.balloonText = "[[title]]:<b>[[value]]</b>";
        graph3.compareGraphBalloonText = "[[title]]:<b>[[value]]</b>";
        graph3.compareGraphBullet = "round";
    graph3.showEventsOnComparedGraphs = true;
        graph3.compareGraphBulletBorderColor = "#FFFFFF";
        graph3.compareGraphBulletBorderAlpha = 1;
    graph3.valueAxis = valueAxis3;
        stockPanel.addStockGraph(graph3);
    
        // graph of fourth stock panel
        var graph4 = new AmCharts.StockGraph();
    graph4.comparable = true;
        graph4.valueField = "value4";
        graph4.title = "Value4";
        graph4.useDataSetColors = false;
        graph4.lineColor = colors[3];
        graph4.bullet = "round";
        graph4.bulletBorderColor = "#FFFFFF";
        graph4.bulletBorderAlpha = 1;
        graph4.balloonText = "[[title]]:<b>[[value]]</b>";
        graph4.compareGraphBalloonText = "[[title]]:<b>[[value]]</b>";
        graph4.compareGraphBullet = "round";
        graph4.compareGraphBulletBorderColor = "#FFFFFF";
        graph4.compareGraphBulletBorderAlpha = 1;
    graph4.valueAxis = valueAxis4;
        stockPanel.addStockGraph(graph4);
    
        // create stock legend                
        var stockLegend1 = new AmCharts.StockLegend();
        stockLegend1.periodValueTextComparing = "[[percents.value.close]]%";
        stockLegend1.periodValueTextRegular = "[[value.close]]";
    stockPanel.stockLegend = stockLegend1;
        
    var periodSelector = new AmCharts.PeriodSelector();
        periodSelector.periods = [
  {period: "DD",count: 5,label: "5 day"},{period: "DD",count: 10,label: "10 days"}, 
  {period: "MM",count: 1,label: "1 month",selected: true}, {period: "YYYY",count: 1,label: "1 year"}, 
  {period: "YTD",label: "YTD"}, {period: "MAX",label: "MAX"}];
        periodSelector.position = "left";
        chart.periodSelector = periodSelector;
  
        // DATA SET SELECTOR
        var dataSetSelector = new AmCharts.DataSetSelector();
        dataSetSelector.position = "left";
        chart.dataSetSelector = dataSetSelector;
  
    // set panels to the chart
        chart.panels = [stockPanel];
        
        // OTHER SETTINGS ////////////////////////////////////
        var sbsettings = new AmCharts.ChartScrollbarSettings();
        sbsettings.backgroundColor = "#222";
        sbsettings.selectedBackgroundColor = "#555";
        sbsettings.selectedGraphFillAlpha = 1;
        chart.chartScrollbarSettings = sbsettings;
        
    var chartScrollbar = new AmCharts.ChartScrollbar();
        chartScrollbar.autoGridCount = true;
        chartScrollbar.scrollbarHeight = 40;
        chart.chartScrollbar = chartScrollbar;

        // CURSOR settings
        var cursorSettings = new AmCharts.ChartCursorSettings();
        cursorSettings.valueBalloonsEnabled = true;
    cursorSettings.cursorAlpha = 0.5;
        cursorSettings.valueLineBalloonEnabled = true;
        cursorSettings.valueLineEnabled = true;
        cursorSettings.valueLineAlpha = 0.5;
        cursorSettings.cursorPosition = "mouse";
        chart.chartCursorSettings = cursorSettings;
 
        var categoryAxis = new AmCharts.CategoryAxis();
        chart.categoryAxis = categoryAxis;

        chart.write('chartdiv');
    }
```

```css
  body{
    font-size:12px;
    color:#000000;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    font-family:verdana,helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
  }
  .amChartsButtonSelected{
    background-color:#CC0000;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#CC0000;
    border-width:1px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 1px;
  }
  .amChartsButton{
    background-color:#EEEEEE;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#CCCCCC;
    border-width:1px;
    color:#000000;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 1px;
  }
  .amChartsCompareList{
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#CCCCCC;
    border-width:1px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amstock.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: Here i created the jsfiddle post for the same above example: http://jsfiddle.net/vfz2c7cj/3/